# Finding specific items in a dataframe

Tags: database, dataframe

I have attached an image of a dataframe I am working with.

It is a list of venues in Toronto with their respective neighborhood.

I need to iterate over this dataframe and search for specific venue types. For example, I would like to search for how many pharmacies a specific neighborhood has, and then return the total number of pharmacies.

I would also like to search for libraries, and simply return 1 or 0, (1 if it has 1 or more library, 0 if it has no libraries).

Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: What language do you know?

Comment: I am using pandas in python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task can be solved using just basic functions of *Pandas*,
without reading your DataFrame again (like the other answer suggests).

Define a function:

```
def VenueNo(df, neigh, categ):
    return df.query('Neighborhood == @neigh and `Venue Category` == @categ').index.size
```

Then you can e.g. check how many pools are there in *Parkwoods*
neighborhood running:

```
VenueNo(df, 'Parkwoods', 'Pool')
```

and (for your data sample) the result will be *1*.

I placed parameters in this function to pass all required information,
but if you prefer to rely on global variables, you can e.g.
omit *df* parameter and then this function will look only in one
particular DataFrame.

## Edit

I noticed that you want rather a "0 or 1" answer.

To get it, define another function:

```
def VenuePresent(df, neigh, categ):
    return 1 if df.query('Neighborhood == @neigh and `Venue Category` == @categ')\
        .index.size > 0 else 0
```

Then to test it, run:

```
VenuePresent(df, 'Parkwoods', 'Hockey Arena')
```

and you will get *0*, because there are no hockey arenas in *Parkwoods*
neighborhood.

If you want the possibility to look for **many** categories at once,
change `== @categ` in the function to `in @categ`, but then:

- call this function with *categ* as a **list** of "wanted" categories,
- if you want to look for a **single** category, pass also a list,
  containing just this one category

Comment: Thanks! This is super easy and does exactly what I need it to. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Would I be able to run this to check for more than one venue type at once? For example, check for restaurants, but also check for banks, and return the total number of restaurants + banks?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import csv
from csv import writer
df = pd.read_csv('nameofcsvfile', delimiter=',')
def check(data):
    x = 0
    datainfield = False
    with open('nameofcsvfile', 'rt') as f:
     reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
     try:
         for row in reader:
             for field in row:
               if field == data:
                   print('1')
                   x++
                   datainfield = True
     if datainfield == False:
         print('0 results found')
     else:
         print('there are/is " + str(x) + ' results in the list')
     f.close()
```

I just wrote that in the middle of class so there might be a few bugs but that should work to check data against the csv file